# 22.04: How to change keyring password?

Tags: 22.04, keyrings

On the new installed Ubuntu22.04 I receive the popup to unlock keyring to save password for an app like skype etc.
I enter my current pwd and it is incorrect.
Also, I have tried to change password but the Keyring requires an old pwd.

How to fix it? may be reset pwd somehow?